# Using Jade Tag Interpolation. How to clea nup your code and get rid of unnecessary lines?

Tags: pug

I’m trying to slightly clean up my Jade code removing unnecessary lines. For instance, I have such a snippet:

```
button(ng-click='gameApp.NewGame()') New game
br
```

I’d like to get rid of extra line with `br` tag

I’ve tried [Tag interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) like this:

```
button(ng-click='gameApp.NewGame()') New game#[br]
```

However, this approach inserts `<br/>` inside the button tag:

```
<button ng-click="gameApp.NewGame()">New game<br/></button>
```

Is there other options?

Answer (score 0):

Jade is doing what it is supposed to do. The line break is necessary.

Using your tag interpolation example, Jade has no way of knowing that the contents you are injecting should or should not be enclosed inside the button.

You could try a mixin or use blocks, but it's adding more complexity for little gain.

Use css padding/margins/borders instead of `<br>`, if possible.